# Client - Server communication and Security

Tags: android, http, authentication, ssl

I'm building an Android app that allows users to create an account and insert locally some data to an SQlite DB. The app will be able to sync it's local database with a DB on Server.

As this is the first time i'm trying to implement something like this, i have some questions regarding the security of the transmitted data.

During user's login, registration and data syncs in general i'm thinking of using **basic authentication**. I will sent the mail and password (over HTTPS) to Server on every call. From there (using my hosting credentials for DB connection) i will create a connection to Server's DB and with user's credentials the user will be able to access his own data. Security-wise, **is using SSL enough** or should i also hash the password for extra security?

As far as **user authentication** is concerned, i consider basic authentication more convenient in my case compared to using cookies or JSON web tokens, since user will remain always 'logged-in'.Though, i've read that basic authentication in no - more enough. Can you give some advice on this?